# unhandledRejection {} when using smartpy cli compile/test

Tags: smartpy

I did the installation of https://smartpy.io/docs/cli/ (including python,node and the cli version 0.8.3-1) both in ubuntu (windows subsystem) and in Windows 10 and every time I try to run compile or test (using any of the templates like https://smartpy.io/ide?template=storeValue.py) I'm getting always the message:

```
unhandledRejection {}
```

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: i had the same problem - try `cd`ing into `~/smartpy-cli` and running `npm install @smartpy/timelock`

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Windows when running Ubuntu via WSL 2.0. Using SmartPy Version: 0.8.5

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it was fixed as soon as I updated Node to the newer LTS version 16.13.1

```
# download latest nvm
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
# after installing restart shell or add export variables for nvm to work

# then install the newer node version
nvm install 16.13.1
```

Comment: This fix worked for me using WSL2 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

it worked with me finalllly, am using WSL2 on windows 11 ... the script is very restricted in terms where you put the files ...even if you are at the smartpy-cli folder you still need to write the full command as follow:

```
~/smartpy-cli/SmartPy.sh test ~/smartpy-cli/contracts/play.py ~/smartpy-cli/test
```

you have to create the "contracts" and "test" folders and copy your python files in "contracts"

Comment: This was it for me. The older version used to not care.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This has been fixed on Saturday, you just need to update the CLI by running this:</strike>

<strike>`sh <(curl -s https://smartpy.io/cli/install.sh)`</strike>

Ignore my previous message (I just read your message properly), SmartPy CLI doesn't work on windows without using a container or WSL.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on WSL, just FYI.